# Error valor NAN input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo dos funciones las cuales resumiendo, la primera de ellas se encarga de recoger el value de un input de tipo string, chequea si existe el carácter "-" mediante indexOf, elimina todos los caracteres menos los numéricos, y dependiendo el resultado de indexOf cambia el número de positivo a negativo,es decir un ejemplo, si el value original **fuese irpf-7%**, el resultado de toda la primera función seria:**-7** de tipo string ya que necesito hacer otro segundo indexOf en la segunda función.

La segunda función lo que hace res recoger la variable impuesto de tipo de cadena y realiza el segundo indexOf el cual si es negativo accede a un if, en ese if se formulan una serie de operaciones y devuelve un resultado final de tipo float llamado **"resta"**. Mi problema esta en que los console.log(resta) funcionan y me devuelven correctamente el resultado que necesito pero en le input total-1 me da un error diciéndome que no es un número válido (NAN).

**Resultados concole.log()**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//**Code first function**

function value_impuestos() {

  if (un_articulo == true) {
    impuestos1 = $("#impuestos1-1").val();
    negativo_positivo = impuestos1.indexOf("-");
    impuesto = impuestos1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
    if (negativo_positivo == 0) {
      x = impuesto;
      impuesto = x * -1;
      impuesto = impuesto.toString();
    }
  }
}

// **Code second function**

$("select[id=impuestos1-1]").change(function() {

  value_impuestos();
impuesto1=impuesto;
  positivo_negativo = impuesto1.indexOf("-") > -1;
  if (positivo_negativo == true) {

    precio = $("#precio-1").val();
    cantidad = $("#cantidad-1").val();
    cantidad_precio = cantidad * precio;
    impuesto = impuesto1.replace("-", "");
    division = cantidad_precio / 100;
    multiplicacion = division * impuesto;

    resta = parseFloat(cantidad_precio) - parseFloat(multiplicacion);

    $("#impuestos1-1").data("impuestos1", multiplicacion);

    console.log(Number.isNaN(resta));
    console.log(typeof resta);
    console.log(resta);

    $("#total-1").val(resta);


  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control widthInput2 total" id="total-1" name="materiales[1][total]" type="number" placeholder="Calcular.." readonly>
```

Comment: como tu input resive `irpf-7%` si es de `type="number"` podrias agregar el valor de entrada y el resultado esperado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás complicando un poco la lógica, porque no es necesaria una función aparte para obtener/sanear el impuesto, además de que no estás declarando variables para tenerlas en el mismo contexto en ambas funciones.

También debes asegurarte de que todos los datos tienen un valor numérico válido, ya sea usando *parseFloat* o *parseInt*, depende del dato que esperas y considerando que estas funciones devolverán NaN si el campo está vacío, basta agregar al final `|| 0`.

Las operaciones también son muy sencillas:

- Calcular subtotal, multiplicando cantidad * precio
- Calcular impuesto aplicable, multiplicando subtotal * impuesto y dividiendo entre 100
- Calcular total, sumando subtotal e impuesto aplicable, si el porcentaje de impuesto es negativo se realizará resta automáticamente

```js
$("select[id=impuestos1-1]").change(function() {
    // En la misma función obtienes impuesto y eliminas caracteres no numéricos
    let impuestos1 = $("#impuestos1-1").val();
    let negativo = impuestos1.indexOf("-") > -1;
    let impuesto = parseFloat(impuestos1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) || 0;
    if(negativo) {
        // Aplicar negativo
        impuesto *= -1;
    }
    // Realizar cálculos para cualquier impuesto
    let precio = parseFloat($("#precio-1").val()) || 0;
    let cantidad = parseFloat($("#cantidad-1").val()) || 0;
    if(precio == 0 || cantidad == 0) {
        console.log('Teclea cantidad y precio, no deben ser cero');
        return;
    }
    let subtotal = precio * cantidad;
    let calculo = subtotal * impuesto / 100;
    // Si el impuesto es negativo, se realizará resta
    let total = subtotal + calculo;
    $("#total-1").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cantidad-1" type="number" placeholder="Precio">
<input id="precio-1" type="number" placeholder="Cantidad">
<select id="impuestos1-1">
    <option>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="srf-7%">srf-7%</option>
    <option value="otro10%">otro10%</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control widthInput2 total" id="total-1" name="materiales[1][total]" type="number" placeholder="Calcular.." readonly>
```